# adding a new project to an existing remote in git which has content already

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a remote in git

It contains a project already.

I'm using eclipse and sourceTree.

how can I add a newly created project to it?

by project I mean another code folder which depend on the already uploaded project.

Comment: By project do you mean a new branch that shares some of the same code and history?  If not the best practice is to create a new repository.

Comment: by project I mean another code folder which depend on the already uploaded project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to run into at least one problem here: Eclipse will expect the existing project in the remote to be rooted at the root of repository (which I assume it currently is?)

I would just create a new repository, it's going to be simpler. On GitHub you can create an organization to group related repositories together.